# WordPress Assistance

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem with a WordPress website I am developing. The main menu on the header used to be transparent as shown in the photo attached however I was changing something and it changed to be not transparent as shown to in the picture attached can someone please help me getting it back to the same look.

[The menu look for now which i need to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzzUJ.png)[The old menu look i want to restore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lup2S.png)

Answer (score 0):

It'pretty difficult to answer your question, at least explain what you were changing - theme settings / css or what?

Better you can share the admin where you were trying to change the settings.

Comment: Hi actually, the issue is with the css file changing this part in the header where i can make the menu transprent, the theme settings does not support. I hope this would help. Thank you.

Comment: You can check if you have added a CSS that has property of background or background-color or have deleted previous same property..